# SSRS Return tablix cell value using a relative cell reference

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2017

I can return the value in a tablix cell with me.value. My objective is to simply use a background color to show that a value is different, compared to the value above. The tablix is sorted. I wish to return the value of the cell 'above'.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the `Previous` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-previous-function?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL (data source) .. depending on the version you are using.. you could use the LAG function to get "previous" rows data and compare it to current row to find the difference and apply color rules and use that color in your report as a field value.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I with this would work, it does not: =iif(me.value=previous(me.value), "same","different"). This would permit generic code in every cell. It will work with a named field, but then I'll do the check in SQL instead if I must hard code the field name.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multiple places where ME isn't recognized (background color, action...).

Comment: @Harry The LAG function is totally awersome.  It would allow you to grab other column's information as well as other values within a row, depending on how you specify the Over/Order.